# PHPExcel -- Color part of XLSX table

Tags: php, ms-office, phpexcel, xls, xlsx

I need your help, I have a table  with ~ 2000 rows, I would color a part of cells (Ex. Row: 1000 to Row: 2000).
The second question is: how can I format the date automatically? I have this format "21/12/2014  15:08:23" I would format it into "21/12/2014" automatically when I write the new xlsx file.
 What can I do?

Comment: need more explanations pls ?

Comment: I would color part of the table with PHPExcel (P.S. read the update)

Answer (score 0):

To colour the rows:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1000:IV2000')
    ->getFill()
    ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1000:IV2000')
    ->getFill()
    ->getStartColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_BLUE);
```

To format dates:

Make sure that you're setting your date values as an Excel serialized timestamp

```
$myDate = "21/12/2014 15:08:23";
$myDateValue = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $myDate);
$excelTimeStamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($myDateValue);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A1', $excelTimeStamp);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('C9')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY);
```

All of this is covered in the documentation and in the examples provided with the PHPExcel package